# How do I use the partial fractions technique in this case?

Tags: fractions

How do I use the partial fractions technique in this case?

$$\frac{(x - 1)}{(x^2 - x + 1)(x + 1)}$$

Comment: What steps have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: What do you need the decomposition for?

Comment: i don't understand how to find a, b, and c.

Answer (score 3):

The partial fraction decomposition takes the form
$$F(x)=\frac{x-1}{(x^2-x+1)(x+1)}=\frac{a}{x+1}+\frac{bx+c}{x^2-x+1}$$

and notice that
$$a= F(x)(x+1)\bigg|_{x=-1}=-\frac23$$
and $$0=\lim_{x\to\infty}xF(x)=a+b\Rightarrow b=\frac23$$
and finaly
$$F(0)=-1=a+c\Rightarrow c=-\frac13$$

Comment: These are nice techniques